# making a simple text/logo effect for html site?

Tags: jquery, html, flash

Basically I have developed a website, standard html/php etc.

But, what I am now trying to do is when a user first goes to my website to have like a text/logo effect? So I have a logo which is currently an image but when a user goes to the site I want to make the logo break apart and load the homepage?

I have tried searching online to see how to do this but have not really got anywhere. I have adobe flash CS6 and after effects but not sure if those are the appropriate programs?

I want to start with just the logo being there but when the user clicks it, it breaks apart and loads the homepage?..

Comment: Slightly off-topic comment, but something worth considering. In terms of `UX`, that's potentially a bad idea. Just like those ads before a page loads on a site "This page will load in xxx seconds"

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you forget about flash and take a look at some of all these nice javascript libraries out there, Lightbox for example. You could use that to initially show your logo as an image and fade it out when the user clicks/closes it. Demo is here: http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Comment: hi could you tell me where I can find some other effects? other than the lightbox one